# php : cannot see the hidden value submitted by Javascript

Tags: php, javascript, forms, submit

I'm pretty sure I'm missing something simple here, but it's driving me nuts !
This isn't the first form I'm using in PHP, but the first time submitting a hidden value.

When a menu item is clicked, I want to submit the page to itself - setting a simple parameter, so the php code does the processing.

The page gets submitted fine, but the hidden variable I set isn't available through _GET, _POST or _REQUEST. It should be _GET since that is what I've set as the **method**.

Here is the code if anyone can spot where I'm going wrong..
**paramCustom** is the one that I'm trying to set and work on.

The menu is a series of DIVs & anchors :

```
<a href="" onclick="activateMenu('option-xyz');">Option Xyz</a>
```

The activateMenu javascript function is :

```
function activateMenu(optionTaken)
{
    // Set the hidden variable
    document.getElementById('paramCustom').value = optionTaken;

    // Display it to confirm it is set correctly
    var tt = document.getElementById('paramCustom').value;
    console.log("paramCustom set to : " + tt);

    // Submit the form
    document.getElementById('linkSubmit').submit();
    return false;
}
```

The form is coded this way :

```
<form method="get" action="showProducts.php" id="linkSubmit">
    <input type="hidden" id="paramCustom" name="paramCustom" />
    <input type="submit" tabindex="-1" style="display:none;" />
</form>
```

In the php of the same page I'm trying to spit them out but all of them show blank !!

```
echo "paramCustom get is : ".$_GET['paramCustom']."<br/>"; // This should work
echo "paramCustom request is : ".$_REQUEST['paramCustom']."<br/>";
echo "paramCustom post is : ".$_POST['paramCustom']."<br/>";
```

Comment: @zdhickman The hidden field type prevents HTML from rendering the field in the page.  The value is still submitted regardless of the form method.

Comment: Have you tried printing the `$_GET` array, to see what is there?  ie. `echo "<pre>".print_r($_GET,1)."</pre>";`

Comment: If your javascript fails your value will be null, have you checked the console?

Comment: @LightStyle no errors in the console.

Comment: @Sean let me try printing it out.

Comment: Have you tried to put an `alert('click fired');` inside the event handler? Are you sure the event is fired?

Comment: @LightStyle it did fire.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, problem is that you are not actually stopping the event from firing. So clicking on the link, the function gets called, form submitted but you are not actually stopping the event in the `onclick`. So form submits but is immediately redirected to the href of the link cancelling the form submit. When the href is blank, it defaults back to the page you are currently on.

The way you are adding the `onclick` to the link (using an inline attribute) is like wrapping the event in a closure. So when `onclick` fires, what is really fired is more like `function(){ activateMenu('option-xyz'); }`. Your call to activateMenu is returning false, but the closure around it is not. You can just add `return` in front of `activateMenu` to have the event itself return false and cancel. Change the link like so:

```
<a href="" onclick="return activateMenu('option-xyz');">Option Xyz</a>
```

And then the actual event itself will return false, not just the function.

[Here is a simple example to illustrate what is happening.](http://jsbin.com/ufusul/1)

Comment: THANKS A LOT !! This solved it. Now I'm going to devour this concept so I never get this close to pulling my hair off :)

Comment: Thanks for explaining the closure angle. So when we put anything in onclick, it is automatically wrapped in a function(){} internally ? Or is that just an example ?

Comment: You can also avoid the issue by using href="javascript:activateMenu('option-xyz');" instead of the onclick.

Comment: @PlanetUnknown When you assign the onclick as an attribute (inline on the tag like you are doing) that is exactly what is happening. You can see this if you alert the onclick attribute in js like `alert(document.getElementById('someElementWithOnclick').onclick);`. If you assign the onclick event in javascript, you are supplying the closure/function. It doesn't get wrapped in another closure by the browser.

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't work because you haven't assigned a value.  PHP won't recognize a field with a null value.

```
<input type="hidden" id="paramCustom" name="paramCustom" value="somevaluehere" />
```

[edit]
After testing this myself, it's because the onclick event is not behaving the way you anticipate.  The easiest way to fix this is to use a HREF for you link.  It's actually bad practice to rely solely on the onclick event anyway.

```
<a href="javascript:activateMenu('option-xyz');">Option Xyz</a>
```

This works perfectly.

The proper way to write an onclick looks like this:

```
<a href="" onclick="activateMenu('option-xyz');return false;">Option Xyz</a>
```

This works as well.

Comment: That didn't make any difference.

Answer (score 0):

Doing a little change to the HTML you can set the inline event via Javascript, which is a way better:

```
<a id="xyz" href="#">Option Xyz</a>
```

And this is the Javascript edited for your purpose:

```
function activateMenu(optionTaken)
{
    var paramCustom = document.getElementById('paramCustom');
    // Set the hidden variable
    paramCustom.value = optionTaken;

    // Display it to confirm it is set correctly
    var tt = paramCustom.value;
    console.log("paramCustom set to : " + tt);

    // Submit the form
    document.getElementById('linkSubmit').submit();
    return false;
}
window.onload = (function() {
    document.getElementById('xyz').onclick = function() {
        activateMenu('option-xyz');
    };
});
```

In PHP, as you know, `$_GET` gets the parameters of query string, `$_POST` of the POST data and `$_REQUEST` is a concat of the two arrays. In this case your method is GET so the value can be retrieved via _GET and _REQUEST, _POST is not going to work. Your code didn't worked to me probably because you had your function defined before DOM was loaded, so the event, when fired, probably throwed an exception.

Comment: Read the updated answer, if the problem is not the event I'll remove the answer obviously!

Comment: @PlanetUnknown can you try it?

Comment: The problem isn't the event.  The problem is that the OP didn't supply a value in the hidden field for the form to submit.  It's not working because there is no value!

Comment: No, if you read the JS it changes the value of the hidden input before submitting the form. If the JS doesn't work it is right that the value of the hidden input is null, if it works then the value will be there and will be print by the server

Answer (score -2):

I've been using JQuery lately and it might be worth a shot.

Download the latest JQuery script and just link it to your page.

```
function activateMenu(optionTaken)
{
    // Set the hidden variable
    $("#paramCustom").val() = optionTaken;

    // Display it to confirm it is set correctly
    var tt = $("#paramCustom").val();
    console.log("paramCustom set to : " + tt);

    // Submit the form
    document.getElementById('linkSubmit').submit();
    return false;
}
```

This isn't that much different than what you had but maybe JQuery will do a better job of assigning the value to your hidden field...

Cheers,

K

Comment: `$("#paramCustom").val() = optionTaken;` this is an error. Anyway, jQuery is not necessary in this case, I don't understand the need of using it.